# How can I use wget to download a list of links from NOAA NCEI?

Tags: recursion, curl, hyperlink, download, wget

I need to download public bathymetry data from NOAA NCEI. Often, this means I need to download hundreds of small files to later be stitched together. NOAA NCEI has a tool for this -- "request files": click request, enter your email, and wait for them to send you a zipped folder of all the files. This can take >1 week, and sometimes requests fail without your knowledge. I would like to avoid that method. Below is an example data source:

https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/ships/nautilus/NA072_mb.html

Ultimately, I would like to use wget/curl to download every .gz file from an NCEI page such as that. I noticed that on the page all the file links are present. You can right click->open in new window->enter to download a single file immediately. If you do this, it redirects to a link like this:

http://data.ngdc.noaa.gov/platforms/ocean/ships/nautilus/NA072/multibeam/data/version2/MB/em302/0000_20160601_180321_Nautilus_EM302.gsf.mb121.gz

How can I use a command line tool like wget to download all .gz files from a page like this?

I have tried commands such as:

wget --execute="robots = off" -A.gz --mirror --convert-links --no-parent [url]

but I get one of two errors for the .gz files:

"Unable to establish SSL connection."

or

"HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently"

Comment: I've been working on a script that solves a similar problem. I don't have the time to work on it right now, but basically you have  identified the steps. Get the main list, extract just the URLs, call each URL to get the redirected URL and then use that for your final `curl` command. If you get more reputation points we can have a private chat about it. Post a simplier question that people can answer without a lot of research and you're likey to get some upvotes. Maybe able to work on my version next week. Good luck.

Comment: Rather than try to solve this all-in-one, get the first 2 steps to  work. With what you learn there, it will be easier to construct the final 2 steps. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/ships/nautilus/NA072_mb.html but links are like http://data.ngdc.noaa.gov/platforms/ocean/ships/nautilus/NA072/multibeam/data/version2/MB/em302/0000_20160601_180321_Nautilus_EM302.gsf.mb121.gz so they are *different hosts*, by default `wget` does not crawl to other hosts, you should combine `--recursive` with `-H` to do so, consult [Spanning Hosts](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Spanning-Hosts.html) for more information.

I suggest using following command

```
wget --recursive --level=1 -H --accept gz 'https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/ships/nautilus/NA072_mb.html'
```

beyond mentioned `--recursive` `-H` combination I limited level (depth) to 1, meaning that I want only links present at given page (not links in linked page &c) and to `gz` files. Please try running that command and write if it does downloaded desired files.

Comment: Unfortunately, this fails in the same manner.
And I did remove the quotes to avoid the 'scheme missing' error.

Comment: Can anyone reliably get this to download?
http://data.ngdc.noaa.gov/platforms/ocean/ships/nautilus/NA072/multibeam/data/version2/MB/em302/0000_20160601_180321_Nautilus_EM302.gsf.mb121.gz

Comment: Hmm. Reliably? I just used my Firefox browser, pasted your URL in and was able to capture the file. I tried the same URL with `curl`, but that failed. Use the exact `wget` command from above, and that worked (quite a ton of data!). Going to experiment more with `curl` options. Good luck.

Comment: Well, `wget --recursive --level=1 -H --accept gz "http://data.ngdc.noaa.gov/platforms/ocean/ships/nautilus/NA072/multibeam/data/version2/MB/em302/0000_20160601_180321_Nautilus_EM302.gsf.mb121.gz"` (using your URL) (seemed to have) worked also. What do you mean reliably? Does this never work for you or just sometimes. Possibly network problems are causing failures? Maybe use the `-d` (debug) option and parse for errors. When errors found, you have to programatically retry. I had numerous `sftp` production jobs where I had to do this.  Edit your Q to expand the details of your usecase. Good Luck

Comment: Neither of the commands suggested above ever worked for me on my windows workstation.

I just tried the suggested commands on my macbook (not my windows workstation) and both worked. Same network as before, so it is clearly an issue with my windows config of wget. Thank you to shellter and daweo for working solutions.

FYI I was using the windows-wget version v1.21.4, and can use wget to download from other sites. Still not sure why this doesn't work.